# There was no endpoint listening at https://

Tags: c#, ssl, https, asmx

I'm developing a web application that must communicate with a third-party web service provided by an external company. The ws works with https on port 443 with SSL (VeriSign). I have user name and password that I have to put inside the request body of the SOAP message. I have provided to the external company the public IP of my company because they probably had to register it. 
I added a service reference to my project providing the url of the ws (for ex. https://domain.com/ws/Test.asmx.
I was able to build the request but when I try to call the web service I get the following exception:

**"There was no endpoint listening at https://domain.com/ws/Test.asmx that could accept the message. This is often  caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more  details."**

Here is an extract from the app.config (replicated in the Web.config):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TestSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://domain.com/ws/Test.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestSoap"
      contract="Test.TestSoap" name="TestSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'am able to open the wsdl inside my browser. The Innerexception is "The remote name could not be resolved: 'domain.com'"

Any help??? I'm going mad! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the service on port 443 from the client machine? Can you negotiate SSL with it? Try

```
openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443 -showcerts < /dev/null
```

from the client machine.

Comment: I get "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Sorry, on Windows, you don't want /dev/null, you want NUL (if I recall correctly). So, untested, but it would be: `openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443 -showcerts < NUL`